# Anomalous result using bash "set" command

Tags: bash, command-line

When one issues the `set` command without arguments at a bash prompt (which should output a list of shell variables and their values), a script of 8,274 lines scrolls by.  Examining this script shows that it is instructions to the shell for executing commands - and it seems that it runs python scripts, making it essentially a kludge of monstrous proportions.  I've seen other builtins behave in a few ways

No output:

```
Me:~$ wait
Me:~$ true
Me:~$ test
```

An error, with no usage hint:

```
Me:~$ select
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
```

An error, with usage hint:

```
Me:~$ source
bash: source: filename argument required
source: usage: source filename [arguments]
Me:~$ return
bash: return: can only `return' from a function or sourced script
```

I'm having trouble understanding why `set` behaves in this way. It seems undocumented, and I wasn't really expecting it. I'm troubled as to why this happens. Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those 8k lines are mainly completion functions from the bash-completion package. On my old desktop, bash uses almost a second to read through and define all those functions, most of which I never use, so I disable it.

To disable it, edit your ~/.bashrc, locate these three lines near the end, and prepend a `#` to each of the lines.

```
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
fi
```

Next time you run an interactive bash session, `set` will only output about 50-100 lines; mostly environment variables and special shell variables.

Comment: This explains what is going on here.  Thank you very much.  Running "set" without arguments should display the variables that are "set."

Comment: @Eric Weir If you only want to see variables set, you can also use `declare -p` it also shows you what type of variable it is. `declare -f` shows functions. Run `help declare` for a quick overview of how to use it and read its output.

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html:

> If no options or arguments are supplied, set displays the names and values of all shell variables and functions, sorted according to the current locale, in a format that may be reused as input for setting or resetting the currently-set variables.

The same documentation, but with some examples, can be found at: http://ss64.com/bash/set.html, and the command `help set` gives a summary of that information.

So the behavior you describe is indeed correct.  I agree that it would be nice if there were a `--help` option; generally when all of `man set`, `apropos set`, `which set`, and `whatis set` fail to be helpful, I will try to pass `--help` as an option.  Doing so prevents a command from running with unexpected results, as it will either give me a help message, or trigger an error.  In this case:

```
$ set --help
bash: set: --: invalid option
set: usage: set [-abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option-name] [--] [arg ...]
```

I find this trick to be a useful failsafe.

I should point out that the first few Google results for "bash set" led me to this documentation.

Comment: Thanks for answering.  There is a help option, as you say; it's "help set".  Otherwise, I think you did not understand the issue, because I'm not sure what your proposed answer is.  No, the behavior I described is not correct; see the answer from geirha.

Comment: The way I read your post, you had three 'questions': (1) "It seems undocumented", which I took as an implicit version of the question "Why isn't this documented / where is this documented?" (2) "It is an unexpected result", which I took as an implicit version of the question "Is this an unexpected result" and (3) "I seem not to like it", which is not a question at all. Phoenix answered the first two as best he could given your ambiguity.

Comment: Also, they behavior you described is perfectly correct. As per his first link.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `set | more` and watch near the bottom of the first screen. You'll likely see something like this:

```
SSH_CLIENT='XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX 54284 22'
SSH_CONNECTION='XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX 54284 68.232.126.14 22'
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/0
TERM=xterm
UID=114
USER=XXXXXXX
XDG_SESSION_COOKIE=740274408c1d635200f7415f00000009-1329686026.470247-1256968508
_=
__grub_script_check_program=grub-script-check
_scp_path_esc='[][(){}<>",:;^&!$=?`|\\'\''[:space:]]'
__expand_tilde_by_ref ()
{
    if [ "${!1:0:1}" = "~" ]; then
        if [ "${!1}" != "${!1//\/}" ]; then
...output truncated...
```

so the script your are referring to is a cleverly (if not clearly) escaped shell variable. As for `wait`,`test`, and `true`. Those are all documented with man pages. Issue `man <command>` to find out more about them. Blank output is the expected result of those functions.

Comment: Thanks for answering.  I don't think so. Running "set |more" does not turn the output into a shell variable.  And by the way, did you try "man wait" yourself?  You do not get the bash shell command "wait" when you do.

Comment: I actually didn't try `wait`, I tried `test` and `true` because I happened to know they were both builtins. Seems `wait` is not, but that should have been apparent because `man wait` yields an entry from section 2 (system calls), which is why `which wait` returns nothing.

Comment: Also, I didn't say it turns the output into a shell variable, I said that output of set happens to contain a script.